# How to use middlewares when using julienschmidt/httprouter in goLang?

Tags: go, middleware

What's the best way to chain middlewares while using julienschmidt/httprouter?

As far as I have googled, http.HandlerFunc accepts functions only in the form `func (w ResponseWriter, r *Request)` whereas httprouter.Handle functions are of the form `func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params)`.

How to I chain middlewares without converting the httprouter.Handle function into http.HandlerFunc?

For example:
My routes.go is of the form,

```
router  :=  httprouter.New()
router.POST("/api/user/create", middlewares.EscapeStringsMiddleware(User.CreateUser))
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000",  router))
```

How do I write middleware functions for the above mentioned route?

**Already tried methods:**

1.

```
func EscapeStringsMiddleware(next http.Handler) httprouter.Handle {

    return func (response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
        err := request.ParseForm()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        for key, values := range request.Form {
            for i, value := range values {
                value = template.HTMLEscapeString(value)
                value = template.JSEscapeString(value)
                request.Form[key][i] = value
            }
        }
        next.ServeHTTP(response, request)
    }
}
```

**Error obtained:**

```
cannot use User.CreateUser (type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request, httprouter.Params)) as type http.Handler in argument to middlewares.EscapeStringsMiddleware:
func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request, httprouter.Params) does not implement http.Handler (missing ServeHTTP method)
```

2.

```
func EscapeStringsMiddleware(next httprouter.Handle) httprouter.Handle {

    return func (response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
        err := request.ParseForm()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        for key, values := range request.Form {
            for i, value := range values {
                value = template.HTMLEscapeString(value)
                value = template.JSEscapeString(value)
                request.Form[key][i] = value
            }
        }
        next.ServeHTTP(response, request)
    }
}
```

**Error obtained:**

```
next.ServeHTTP undefined (type httprouter.Handle has no field or method ServeHTTP)
```

Also how do I chain multiple middleware?

For example,

```
router.POST("/api/user/create", middlewares.VerifyCSRF(middlewares.EscapeStringsMiddleware(User.CreateUser)))
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This issue is not with your middleware handler. You are getting errs because `User.CreateUser` is not of type `http.Handler`.

Try this pattern :

The important bit is to return a `http.Handler` and wrap `func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)` with `http.HandlerFunc`.

```
func Handler() http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // do stuff
    })
}
```

---

go source :

```
// The HandlerFunc type is an adapter to allow the use of
// ordinary functions as HTTP handlers. If f is a function
// with the appropriate signature, HandlerFunc(f) is a
// Handler that calls f.
type HandlerFunc func(ResponseWriter, *Request)

// ServeHTTP calls f(w, r).
func (f HandlerFunc) ServeHTTP(w ResponseWriter, r *Request) {
    f(w, r)
}
```

---

Based on your feedback:

`httprouter.Handle` does not implement `ServeHTTP`. It is called directly. For example : `next(w, r, ps)`

Below you will find examples of middleware handlers.

```
// Middleware without "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
func StdToStdMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {

    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // do stuff
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

// Middleware for a standard handler returning a "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter" Handle
func StdToJulienMiddleware(next http.Handler) httprouter.Handle {

    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
        // do stuff
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
}

// Pure "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter" middleware
func JulienToJulienMiddleware(next httprouter.Handle) httprouter.Handle {

    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
        // do stuff
        next(w, r, ps)
    }
}

func JulienHandler() httprouter.Handle {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
        // do stuff
    }
}

func StdHandler() http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // do stuff
    })
}

func main() {
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.POST("/api/user/create", StdToJulienMiddleware(StdHandler()))
    router.GET("/api/user/create", JulienToJulienMiddleware(JulienHandler()))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", router))
}
```

Comment: User.CreateUser is of type httprouter.Handle i.e., `func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params)`. I would also consider passing parameters to this function. Also, if I chain multiple middlewares, how does this code change in the parent middleware?
i.e.,
`router.POST("/api/user/create", middlewares.VerifyCSRF(middlewares.EscapeStringsMiddleware(User.CreateUser)))`

Comment: @RohithBalaji post a full runnable example with the error, then I can say more

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/cnvrtly/adaptr lib where adapters are also added to chain request middleware functions.

```
func compatibleHandler(h http.Handler, httprParamsCtxKey interface{}) httprouter.Handle {
return toHttpRouterHandle(h, httprParamsCtxKey)
}
func toHttpRouterHandle(h http.Handler, httprParamsCtxKey interface{}) func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) {
   return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) {
    if httprParamsCtxKey != nil {
        r = SetCtxValue(r, httprParamsCtxKey, p)
    }
    h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
   }
}
```

If you are looking for example/idea how to define routes: https://github.com/cnvrtly/golang-appengine-seed